# Weather app, openweathermap.org/api the data are not loading

Tags: javascript, api

```js
//FILE index.js

const weather = new Weather ('weatherLocation.city') ;
const ui = new UI();
const storage = new Storage();
const weatherLocation = storage.getLocationData();
document.addEventListener("DOMContetnLoaded", getWeather)
document.getElementById('w-change-btn').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
const city = document.getElementById('city').value;
weather.changeLocation(city);
storage.setLocationData(city);
getWeather();
$('#locModal').modal('hide');
})
function getWeather() {
weather.getWeather()
.then(results => {
ui.paint(results);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}

//FILE ui.js

class UI {
constructor() {
this.location = document.getElementById('w-location');
this.desc = document.getElementById('w-desc');
this.string = document.getElementById('w-string');
this.details = document.getElementById('w-details');
this.icon = document.getElementById('w-icon');
this.humidity = document.getElementById('w-humidity');
this.maxTemp = document.getElementById('w-maxtemp');
this.pressure = document.getElementById('w-pressure');
this.wind = document.getElementById('w-wind');
}
paint(weather) {
this.location.textContent = weather.name;
this.desc.textContent = weather.weather[0].main;
this.string.textContent = weather.main.temp + "℃";
 
this.icon.setAttribute('src', `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weather.weather[0].icon}.png`);
this.humidity.textContent = `Relative Humidity: ${weather.main.humidity} %`;
this.maxTemp.textContent = `Maximum Temperature: ${weather.main.temp_max} ℃`;
this.pressure.textContent = `Pressure Level: ${weather.main.pressure}`;
this.wind.textContent = `Wind Speed: ${weather.wind.speed} m/s`;
}
}

//FILE weather.js 

class Weather {
constructor(city){
this.apiKey = '871f423b3e84cd9f55df405c88cee62d';
this.city = city;
}
async getWeather(){
const response = await fetch (`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.city}&APPID=${this.apiKey}&units=metric`)
const responseData = await response.json();
return responseData;
}
changeLocation(city){
this.city = city;
}
}

//FILE storage.js

class Storage{
constructor(){
this.city;
this.defaultCity = "Prague"
}
getLocationData(){
if( localStorage.getItem('city') === null){
this.city = this.defaultCity;
} else {
this.city = localStorage.getItem('city');
}
return {
city:this.city
};
}
setLocationData(city, state){
localStorage.setItem('city', city);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center bg-primary mt-5 p-5 rounded">
<h1 id="w-location"></h1>
<h3 class="text-dark" id="w-desc"></h3>
<h3 id="w-string"></h3>
<img id="w-icon">
<ul id="w-details" class="list-group mt-3">
<li class="list-group-item " id="w-humidity"></li>
<li class="list-group-item " id="w-dewpoint"></li>
<li class="list-group-item " id="w-feels-like"></li>
<li class="list-group-item " id="w-wind"></li> 
</ul>
<hr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#locModal">
Change Location
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="modal fade" id="locModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="locModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="locModalLabel">Choose Location</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="w-form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="city"></label>
<input type="text" id="city" class="form-control">
</div>
 
</form> 
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="w-change-btn">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="storage.js"></script>
<script src="weather.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script src="ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting data from openweathermap.org/api. I obtain api key and security key from  openweathermap.org/api. No data are shown.
I followed instructions and used api from 
but my app does not loading data at all.
Any idea what might go wrong?
![weather app](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/101682904073182759

the code is on my github account:
https://github.com/nansol/WeatherApp

Comment: post your code here

Comment: what is the error (in chrome console)?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: UI is not defined
    at index.js:2

Comment: move the new ui after the class decleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only change declaration sequence (move all class declaration: `UI, Storage, Weather` to the top) it works in [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/h1dL85cz/26/) (but not works in SO snippet due tu SecurityError) So you need to change sequence of your script declaration in bottom of html file to:

```
<script src="ui.js"></script>
<script src="weather.js"></script>
<script src="storage.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```